# Calculate different permutations of prices using PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP script that needs to create a JSON file that includes an array of prices made up of a variety of other prices added together.

For example, I might have a base price of 50 and then a series of add-ons at 5, 10, 15, etc.

So my array would be a combination of all the possible ways those numbers can be added together, 50 + 5, 50 + 5 + 10, and so on.

I also then have a series of multipliers, 1, 3, 6, 12 which have to be multiplied by every number created by the previous step, 3 x (50 + 5), 6 x (50 + 5), and so on.

What I have so far (which involves using the [Violet PHP streaming JSON encoder](https://github.com/violet-php/streaming-json-encoder)) works up to a certain point – about 16 add-ons – but after that, I get memory exhausted or max execution time errors.

I've tried bumping up the limits but that only works for another one or two extra add-ons and then I run into the same problem, and that's on my local version of the site where I can allocate as many resources as I like. I don't have that luxury on the server the site is hosted on.

I'm not sure it's worth posting the code I'm using at the moment because I think it probably has to be started over from scratch.

And I don't really know how to approach the task so that the script can confidently handle any number (within reason) of add-ons without the server running out of resources.

Comment: I think this is called "exponential growth". Dealing with the memory problem is possible, but since the number of results grows exponentially it will be hard to reduce the time it takes.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware While thinking about replying to your comment, an idea occurred to me. Some of the products I need to create JSON files for only have a single multiplier. Those products, at the moment, are able to successfully generate a JSON file. It's the ones with more multipliers that fail. So I could possibly run the process for each multiplier separately, creating separate files and then combine them together at the end.

Comment: Sounds like you found a fix yourself. Anyway, memory really should be a problem, you're streaming the JSON to a file and the loops themselves shouldn't take much space on the stack. It's weird to me that you run out of space.